# creating images from disk with smaller footprint

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a running gce instance setup the way I want, I would like to create an image to boot up with next time. However, the current disk size is quite large and only a small fraction is used. Is there a way to create an image but shrink the disk so that I'm not creating a massive image unnecessarily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Compute Engine it is only possible to increase the size of the disk when resizing. However, it is not possible to shrink the disk due to some general file system limitations. That being said the only workaround, I can think is to create a smaller disk and [manually transfer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files) the data.

Additionally, there's currently a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35905012) for this, and I recommend visiting this link to be able to check the progress of issue.